# Can I subtract 2 ciphertexts in FHE exactly?

Tags: homomorphic-encryption

In most FHE schemes, for a polynomial $m_1$,

$$enc(m_1) = a_1*s + e_1 + m_1$$

Suppose I have $enc(m_1),enc(m_2)$. Can I subtract them exactly? Sum works, but subtraction is:

$$enc(m_1) - enc(m_2) = (a_1-a_2)*s + e_1-e_2 + m_1-m_2$$

In the case where $e_1-e_2$ is negative, this gives us problems in the decryption (cleaning of small error bits by shift right). Example:

$$enc(m_1) - enc(m_2) - (a_1-a_2)*s = e_1-e_2 + m_1-m_2$$

the final step for decryption would be $upper(e_1-e_2 + m_1-m_2)$ but if $e_1-e_2$ is negative, it's actually a very large positive (2's complement or in this case, modulus complement), so upper will not work.

Another way would be to transform $enc(m_2)$ into $enc(-m2)$ homomorphically, then do $enc(m_1)+enc(m_2)$ but to do this in some schemes, subtraction is needed, so it won't work.

Comment: I think there is a misconception about which polynomials are used. Coefficients are defined in a ring with representatives centered around 0, e.g., each coefficient is an integer in $\{-q/2+1, ..., 0, ..., q/2\}$. There is no problem on coefficients being on the left part (what you call "negative"). Decryption works as long as some internal value has coefficients close to 0. I think the issue you mention is more an encoding problem, but decryption should not care about this, it only understands polynomials in proper rings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What @zugzwang wrote is indeed correct and here I will expand it a bit more. The basic idea is that there are many ways to represent coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}_q$. Using integers $[0, q-1]$ is one way, and using integers in $[-q/2 + 1, \dots, 0, \dots, q/2]$ is another way. If you view your subtraction operation in the second representation then it works out.

Specifically, to encrypt a value you typically do something like do $E(m) = a \cdot s + \Delta m + e$ where $a$ is a random public ring element, $s$ is the secrete key, $\Delta$ is a scaling factor and $e$ is the added noise. But for the homomorphic operations to be correct, $e$ has to be "small" as you said. Coefficients in $e$ is sampled from a discrete Gaussian distribution with a mean of 0. Typically $e$ only takes values from $\{-1, 0, 1\}$ and majority of the coefficients are 0. Now if we do subtraction, we get
$$
c_0 - c_1 = (as + \Delta m_0 + e_0) - (as + \Delta m_1 + e_1) = as + \Delta(m_0 - m_1) + (e_0 - e_1)
$$
During decryption you subtract $as$ and then round. But $(e_0-e_1)$ is still small so you can recover the plaintext.

Note that in some implementation, the $[0,q-1]$ representation is still used, so coefficients of $e$ would be from $\{q-1, 0, 1\}$. Then you need to do rounding in a different way. If the message is a bit, then you need to round the value to $1$ if it's between $(q/4, 3q/4)$, otherwise you round it to $0$.

Comment: what if `e` is from -10 to 10 (for example) and `\Delta=1`? BFV uses high Delta but for TFHE, `Delta=1`, then we have the subtraction problem I mentioned

Comment: There might some misunderstanding, TFHE doesn't use $\Delta=1$. For plaintext space $t$ you set $\Delta=q/t$. Also there are other types of encoding for float or approximate arithmetic. If your error grows too large then you can't decrypt anymore.

Comment: try with $m_1 = 30$, $m_2=1$, $\Delta=2^7$, $e_1=2$, $e_2=6$, then $e_1-e_2+m_1-m_2 = -4 + (30<<7)-(1<<7) \implies (-4 + (30<<7)-(1<<7))>>7 = 28 \neq 30-1 = 29$

Comment: The $-4$ was supposed to be in the lower bits of $(30<<7)-(1<<7)-4$ but it ends in the higher bits, because the $-4$ in the subtraction borrows all the 0 bits of $(30<<7)-(1<<7)$ until it finds a $1$

Comment: if $-4$ were in the lower bits like $+4$, then $>>7$ would correctly decrypt everything, but $-4$ ends up eating one bit of the encoded message

Comment: what's your plaintext modulus and ciphertext modulus?

Comment: I don't know, still trying to figure out. Do you think for some parameters it can work without this problem I mentioned?

Comment: Actually your example works. $2^7 \cdot (30 - 1) - 4$ is $3708$. Then you do $\mathsf{round}(3708/2^7)$ and that gives you 29 as expected. Shifting right is not the same as rounding.

Comment: @lambda why did you round? The goal was to just remove the lower bits, which a division or shift right would do

Comment: the way the decryption circuit is defined contains division followed by rounding. for example see https://www.zama.ai/post/tfhe-deep-dive-part-1 (just above the toy example)